# Radial Gradient

Tags: javascript, css, gradient, geometry

How do you create a radial gradient for circle **without** using CSS3 (`-webkit-radial-gradient`)?
So lets say I have a circle:

```
#circle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

How do you draw a radial gradient for this circle?

**EDIT:** I would like to do this without any external libraries. Also I am creating the gradient based on color stops. eg (0,255).

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: When you say without CSS3, which style declarations are disallowed?  (Also, we could help you better if we knew why.)

Comment: You say without CSS3, and you used CSS3 decalaration (border-radius)...

Comment: @Damonsson I mean without using the CSS3 declaration "-webkit-radial-gradient".

Comment: It doesn't bit, trust me ;)

Comment: Are you targeting a particular browser/rendering engine? because pretty much any technique of making a radial gradient will use advanced features; the question is, which are available to you?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of methods you can use:

1. You can create an [svg file with a radial gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_radial.asp), and set it as the background using `background-image: url()`
2. You can create a png or jpg of the gradient, and set it the same way as above

If you don't want to use an external file, you could base64 encode it an use a [data url](http://dataurl.net/#look).

You can use `background-size: contain` to make the gradient fit itself to the size of the circle (or ellipse!), just make sure to make the gradient of high enough resolution that it will never get pixellated.

Edit: [Here's a fiddle so you can see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/e2LrV/). since the data url is encoded, here's the source of the svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="-256 -256 512 512"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >
<defs>
  <radialGradient id="grad" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
    <stop stop-color="white" offset="0%"/>
    <stop stop-color="black" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient>
</defs>
<circle r="256px" fill="url(#grad)" />
</svg>
```

You can modify the color stops, then reencode the data uri using [this tool](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker)

Comment: would this count as using external libraries?

Comment: I wouldn't think so… I would consider external libraries to be either browser extensions (like flash) or javascript includes (like jQuery). Since this entire solution can be put into one html file if you want, I don't think it could be argued that it uses external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no standardized or widely supported syntax for radial gradients.

Your best bet to do this with CSS is to use a CSS generator (such as http://westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/ or http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).  These sites handle writing the syntax for each different browser for you.  If you're using LESS or SASS, you can also look into getting a mix-in to handle the variations for you.

If browser specific CSS isn't an option for you, the best option would be to create a background image (be it a PNG or SVG file).